# SQL TOP 1 analog for lists in Python

Tags: python, t-sql

Here is an example of my input csv file:

```
...
0.7,0.5,0.35,14.4,0.521838919218

0.7,0.5,0.35,14.4,0.521893472678

0.7,0.5,0.35,14.4,0.521948026139

0.7,0.5,0.35,14.4,0.522002579599
...
```

I need to select the top row where the last float > random number. My current implementation is very slow (script has a lot of iterations of this and outer cycles):

```
for line in foo:
   if float(line[-1]) > random.random():
      res = line
      break
...
```

How can I make this better and faster?

#### EDIT:

I was advised to use bisect for this task, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Your code (with random.random()) doesn't make sense, since each time you execute the if statement, you have a distinct, new random number.  You'd be better off using random.choice() and just picking any random row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest approach is to use bisect (assuming the float list is ordered). You can do it like this:

```
import bisect

float_list = [line[-1] for line in foo]
index = bisect.bisect(float_list, random.random())
if index < len(float_list)
    result = foo[index]
else:
    result = None # None exists
```

The float list has to be ordered for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You might actually be able to use the appropriate SQL command if you [import the CSV file into SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles).  Python has a [built-in sqlite library](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) you can use to query the database.